# main() is an invalid syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

I use main() to run the program but it keeps calling it an invalid syntax. Even the debugger can't seem to make heads or tails of it. Here's my total code.

```
     """

  InvestmentCalculator.py helps generate how much interest one earns after a certain period of time
 """


 def main():
     total_money = 0
     months_invested = 0
     years_investment = 0

 investment = float(input("How much would you like to invest? "))
 years_investment = float(input("How many years would you like to invest? "))
 interest_rate = float(input("What is the interest rate? "))
 total_money = float()

 months_invested = years_investment / 12
 while months_invested > 0:
     total_money = investment +  total_money
     months_invested = months_invested - 1
     print("You have earned ${:,.2f}".format(total_money))
 else: print("You've earned a total of ${:,.2f}".format(total_money)



 main()
```

Comment: last print is not properly indented and print function brace is not closed.

Comment: There's a syntax error indeed, cf Abhijit's answer. The thing with syntax errors is that they usually can be detected only one or more lines after where they really occur...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a SyntaxError. You missed parentheses for print statement `line: 18`

[image]